# ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE when i try to download csv file?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

When i try to execute this code i get

> ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE
>   and file is not downloaded.

```
    public function downloadcsv(){
      //var_dump($this->export_arr);
      if(isset($_POST['hidden_data'])){
         // echo "hi";
        $exportarr = $_POST['hidden_data'];
        $exportarr = str_replace("\\", "",$exportarr);
        $exportarr = json_decode($exportarr,true);

//      print_r($exportarr[0]);

        $filename = $exportarr[0]['System'] . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Type: text/plain");

        $data = $exportarr;
        //print_r($data);
        $flag = false;
        foreach($data as $key=>$row) {
          if(!$flag) {
            // display field/column names as first row
            echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
            $flag = true;
          }
          array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
          echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
        }
        exit;
      }
    }

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }
```

**NOTICE**: This array is not large.

What cause this?

hidden_data is post data from input hidden:

```
<?php echo form_open("system/downloadcsv",array('class' => 'downloadcsv')); ?>
<input type="hidden" class="hidden_data" name="hidden_data" />
<button type="submit" name="download_csv" class="btn-u btn-u-blue exportsys" disabled="disabled" title="Notice: First run system!">Export</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Also any other file type won't work.

Comment: You get `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE ` where?

Comment: You send twice the `Content-Type` header, remove one.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Same is when i remove text/plain...

Comment: @fusion3k Everywhere, it is some Chrome crash and write just this: This webpage is not available

ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: You could first try to look if the echo you produce in the function is what you expect it to be. So you shouldn't send any headers, but only make plain output you can view in the browser.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I check it already, everything is good.

Comment: Do you get the same error in other browsers?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois On other browsers (IE 11 and Firefox) are 404 errors.
But page exists, because it runs when i remove headers.

Comment: HTTP 404 headers are being sent by the server. Check webserver logfiles.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I don't have permissions..

I tried now outside codeignitier controller and it works now.

Comment: had the same issue, suprisingly could export my excel files only after switching on my error reporting..using codeigniter excel.. Please tag me if anyone knows anything

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37920361/6060968) out

Answer (score 3):

So what you're trying to do is take JSON data from the hidden_data field. Pass it through to the backend. But then have them download the results as a CSV file.

First off. Lets talk about headers. You don't need that many. In fact you're essentially telling the browser to take a crap. If you want the browser to pick up the request as a CSV file these are the two headers that you'll need.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename.csv");
```

Also, you're going to need an actual-ish CSV file to download. PHP uses [streams](http://www.sitepoint.com/%EF%BB%BFunderstanding-streams-in-php/) to deal with this, which is nice because you can also kind of fake one.

```
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
```

Then you can put your columns in however you want using fputcsv

```
foreach($data as $datum) { fputcsv($output, $datum); }
```

In the end. A nice little cleanup of your code might look something like this:

```
public function downloadcsv(){
  if(isset($_POST['hidden_data'])){

    $data = json_decode(
        str_replace('\', '', $_POST['hidden_data']);
    );

    $filename = $data[0]['System'] . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $flag = false;
    foreach($data as $key=>$row) {
      if(!$flag) {
        fputcsv($output(implode(",", array_keys($row)));
        $flag = true;
      }
      array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
      fputcsv(implode(",", array_values($row)));
    }
  }
}
```

I hope that is helpful and gets you on the right track.

[reference](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/)

Comment: Thank you for answer, i already solve it calling script that is outside codeignitier. Probably some headers from ci or maybe wordpress (because i load wp-load.php) cause this.